# Impose numerical limit using mathematics

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to return a number that doesn't exceed a limit I set. For example I want to do the equivalent of:

```
if (number >= limit)
    number = limit;
return number;
```

Is there a mathematical way of doing the equivalent of what I just described in just one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could:

```
return Math.min(number, limit);
```

or:

```
return number >= limit ? limit : number;
```

Comment: That is a good solution, but is there a way to do it on one line? Never mind, just saw your edit.

Comment: @Hayden both solutions are on one line. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll accept your answer once Stack Overflow allows it.

Comment: @Hayden: do you mean a basic mathematical formula using simple operators?

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for a mathematical equation but this answer does the job as well. Just more of a learning experience more than anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the following mathematical formula: (taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/modus-operandi-formulae-for-maximum-and-minimum-of-two-numbers-with-a-b-and))

```
min(a,b) = 1/2 (a + b - |a - b|)
```

Code:

```
return ( number + limit - Math.abs(number - limit) ) / 2;
```

Now `Math.abs` looks pretty similar to `Math.min` (so there wouldn't be much point to using the above instead of simply `Math.min`), although you could easily replace that with the method presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772348/get-absolute-value-without-using-abs-function-nor-if-statement) or [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-integer-absolute-value-abs-without-branching/):

```
mask = n >> 31         // 11111111 for negative and 00000000 for positive
abs = (mask + n)^mask  // convert negative to positive in 2's complement
                       //    while not changing positive
```

Note:

If `number + limit` can overflow, this won't work. This can be changed to
`number - Math.abs(...) + limit` to avoid this, but then `number - Math.abs(...)` can still underflow - you just need to keep overflow in mind and select the option that would prevent over/underflow based on the range of the numbers, or go for the non-arithmetic option.

Also keep in mind that, assuming no over/underflow, if you're dealing with floating point values (`float` / `double`) rather than integral types, the result of the above won't necessarily return either of the values (because of the way floating point representation works).