# How get absolute value only with arithmetic operators?

Tags: c++, math

I'm solving a problem where given two coordinates, calculate the area of the rectangle.

I know that the answer is `abs(x1-x2)*abs(y1-y2)`.

But the problem is for an introduction to C++, and we only know variables and arithmetic.

I don't know if is possible or is a problem to see who know if-statements or abs function

Comment: v * ( (v<0) * (-1) + (v>0)); http://stackoverflow.com/a/9772491/1580953

Comment: do you know std::max and std::min? Because then you could do std::max(x1,x2)-std::min(x1,x2) and similarly for the y's. Even if not you could implement max as (x1<y1)?y1:x1

Comment: what domain and data type? 2'os complement integer or IEEE float/double or something else? can you use `& | ^` and `(condition)?true:false`?

Comment: @Sugar it is not quite a duplicate inasmuch as that is asked about C and this about C++. I noticed that because my max idea is C++ but not C. But it is very true that the ideas there are relevant (and better than mine).

Comment: @JeremyKahan is there any real difference between C++ and C basic numeric types? It's not really language-specific question.

Comment: @Sugar I guess not. And the consensus is with you.

Comment: No, we only know int long long but i get the answer and i dont need abs thnk you, but we dont know bool types and less bit operators